# How to Disable CSRF Protection in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I am Trying to setup a Jenkins pipeline which is supposed to trigger whenever there is a new code push in my bitbucket repository. I tried creating a bitbucket webhook URL `http://<jenkins_URL>/job/<pipeline_name>/build?token=<token_name>` and making it run whenever there is a push in repo. However, whenever there is a push in the repo. the pipeline is not triggered automatically. Upon inspection, i found the webhook is recieving 403 error code from jenkins, with this as body

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/job/<pipeline-name>/build</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.13</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried restarting Jenkins with `hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION=true` property, but it didnt worked. Is there any way I can Disable CSRF, or a better way to automate my pipeline, so that i dont have to disable CSRF at all?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you have to disable CSRF by the following.

Navigate "Manage Jenkins" -> "Script Console".

Than, execute the below.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def instance = Jenkins.instance
instance.setCrumbIssuer(null)
```